# Testing if a jquery approach worked fine

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the easiest way to test performance if a jquery piece of code worked better than the other?

Let's say I have written two pieces of code and want to let my team know which one worked better. How can I do it.

Can you give an example of say inserting elements at runtime in the page and demonstrate the techniques?

Comment: I'd search the Google for **jquery profiling**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-document9999

I would use jsperf for this. Setup of the test cases can be a little tricky but this is by and large the most comprehensive easily shared method for creating performance tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jsPerf.com](http://jsperf.com) for performance tests.

Answer (score 2):

jsperf.com is a powerful javascript testing site